# Function for clean factor levels (Adoption from janitor::clean_names())

Tags: r, data-cleaning, tidy, janitor

I was stupid and coded a lot of my factor labels with "(" or "/". In general it worked for me but now I am at a point (`glht(mod, linfct = c("……"))`) where this doesn't work.

At first I thought "There must be something like the `janitor::clean_names(.)`" but unfortunately I couldn't find something like this. What I am searching for is an automatic function to apply on all factors at once like:
`df%>% mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~f_clean(.x) ) )`

I saw the clean pckg but it needs individual input for the factor levels. Another option I found was a change in the function from the janitor pck what does not work either. Examples can be found below.

Does someone have an idea how to improve this?

Thanks in advance, Luise

EXAMPLES:

```
> #Mess up iris
> iris %>% mutate(Species = fct_recode(Species, `set osa` = "setosa", `versi (color)` = "versicolor",`virgi//nica`="virginica" ))-> temp
> 
> #OPTION 1 
> p_load(clean)
> temp %>%  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~clean_factor(.x ) ))-> i_temp
> get_labels(i_temp$Species)
[1] "set osa"       "versi (color)" "virgi//nica"  
> 
> #OPTION 2
> temp %>% mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~clean_vec(.x) ))-> i_temp
> get_labels(i_temp$Species)
  [1] "set_osa"        "set_osa_2"      "set_osa_3"      "set_osa_4"      "set_osa_5"      "set_osa_6"      "set_osa_7"     
  [8] "set_osa_8"      "set_osa_9"      "set_osa_10"     "set_osa_11"     "set_osa_12"     "set_osa_13"     "set_osa_14"    
 [15] "set_osa_15"     "set_osa_16"     "set_osa_17"     "set_osa_18"     "set_osa_19"     "set_osa_20"     "set_osa_21"    
 [22] "set_osa_22"     "set_osa_23"     "set_osa_24"     "set_osa_25"     "set_osa_26"     "set_osa_27"     "set_osa_28"    
 [29] "set_osa_29"     "set_osa_30"     "set_osa_31"     "set_osa_32"     "set_osa_33"     "set_osa_34"     "set_osa_35"    
 [36] "set_osa_36"     "set_osa_37"     "set_osa_38"     "set_osa_39"     "set_osa_40"     "set_osa_41"     "set_osa_42"    
 [43] "set_osa_43"     "set_osa_44"     "set_osa_45"     "set_osa_46"     "set_osa_47"     "set_osa_48"     "set_osa_49"    
 [50] "set_osa_50"     "versi_color"    "versi_color_2"  "versi_color_3"  "versi_color_4"  "versi_color_5"  "versi_color_6" 
 [57] "versi_color_7"  "versi_color_8"  "versi_color_9"  "versi_color_10" "versi_color_11" "versi_color_12" "versi_color_13"
 [64] "versi_color_14" "versi_color_15" "versi_color_16" "versi_color_17" "versi_color_18" "versi_color_19" "versi_color_20"
 [71] "versi_color_21" "versi_color_22" "versi_color_23" "versi_color_24" "versi_color_25" "versi_color_26" "versi_color_27"
 [78] "versi_color_28" "versi_color_29" "versi_color_30" "versi_color_31" "versi_color_32" "versi_color_33" "versi_color_34"
 [85] "versi_color_35" "versi_color_36" "versi_color_37" "versi_color_38" "versi_color_39" "versi_color_40" "versi_color_41"
 [92] "versi_color_42" "versi_color_43" "versi_color_44" "versi_color_45" "versi_color_46" "versi_color_47" "versi_color_48"
 [99] "versi_color_49" "versi_color_50" "virgi_nica"     "virgi_nica_2"   "virgi_nica_3"   "virgi_nica_4"   "virgi_nica_5"  
[106] "virgi_nica_6"   "virgi_nica_7"   "virgi_nica_8"   "virgi_nica_9"   "virgi_nica_10"  "virgi_nica_11"  "virgi_nica_12" 
[113] "virgi_nica_13"  "virgi_nica_14"  "virgi_nica_15"  "virgi_nica_16"  "virgi_nica_17"  "virgi_nica_18"  "virgi_nica_19" 
[120] "virgi_nica_20"  "virgi_nica_21"  "virgi_nica_22"  "virgi_nica_23"  "virgi_nica_24"  "virgi_nica_25"  "virgi_nica_26" 
[127] "virgi_nica_27"  "virgi_nica_28"  "virgi_nica_29"  "virgi_nica_30"  "virgi_nica_31"  "virgi_nica_32"  "virgi_nica_33" 
[134] "virgi_nica_34"  "virgi_nica_35"  "virgi_nica_36"  "virgi_nica_37"  "virgi_nica_38"  "virgi_nica_39"  "virgi_nica_40" 
[141] "virgi_nica_41"  "virgi_nica_42"  "virgi_nica_43"  "virgi_nica_44"  "virgi_nica_45"  "virgi_nica_46"  "virgi_nica_47" 
[148] "virgi_nica_48"  "virgi_nica_49"  "virgi_nica_50" 
> 
> 
> #SOLUCTION NOT VERY HANDY
> clean_vec(get_labels(temp$Species)) %>% dput
c("set_osa", "versi_color", "virgi_nica")
> temp %>%  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~clean_factor(.x,c("set_osa", "versi_color", "virgi_nica") ) ))-> i_temp
These factor levels were not found in the data: set_osa, versi_color, virgi_nica
> get_labels(i_temp$Species)
[1] "set_osa"     "versi_color" "virgi_ni
```

Answer (score 0):

`clean_character` can use `remove` argument

```
library(clean)
library(dplyr)
library(sjlabelled)
i_temp <- temp %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~
       as.factor(clean_character(.x, remove = "[[:punct:] ]"))))
```

-checking

```
> get_labels(i_temp$Species)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```